# How to store unicode character of numeric value and thats works like simple datatype int

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In a MySQL table, I want to store the numeric value unicode form of Gujarati file name RS and also I want to get data using `group by` query using `sum` function then how I can?

For example I have table:

```
 a(no int,RS int/varchar(10)utf8_unicode_ci)
```

and I get data using this query:

```
 select sum(RS) from a
```

insert data:

```
INSERT INTO `a` (`no`, `rs`) VALUES
(10, '૧૨૩'),
(9, '૧૦૦'),
(8, '૧૨');
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here. Is there a reason storing the actual unicode characters won't work? Why do you need to do the "select sum(RS)"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform arithmetic manipulations on a column the only practical approach is to save the values in a true numeric column. Trying to save numbers as text and constantly converting them back and forth to numbers would not only be a nuisance, it could very well introduce any number of subtle little bugs into your application.

In other words, you are confusing the **data** with the **presentation of the data**. If you store the numbers *as numbers* at the data level then the presentation logic can format those numbers in any number of different ways. Probably the lowest-level place to look for ways to present numbers as *Gujarati numbers* would be the "Use native digits" setting in Windows' "Regional and Language Options" control panel:

[image: regional.png]